# Python: IDE in one computer, interpreter in other

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'd like to know if it is possible to have the interpreter of Python installed in one computer and having an IDE "linked" to that interpreter in other one, i.e.: I want to program some scripts for my Raspberry Pi, but it is too slow if using X Window, and too tedious if doing the work in "command line" mode (open nano, edit, save, close, try, debug, etc.).

So, the idea is having the IDE in my laptop, and the script and linker in my Raspberry Pi.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What linker? And what's wrong with just copying the files over to run the tests?

Comment: Any decent IDE will have support for SSH/SCP or FTP or storing the files on a network mount. PyCharm definitely has this functionality, have used that in the past in the same way.

Comment: @honk I guess that could be a workaround, but I was asking specifically if this thing I thought could be done. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PyCharm has [remote debugging support](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/remote-debugging.html).

PyDev [also supports remote debugging](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html).

Answer (score 0):

maybe git hooks will suite well? I'm using it for some sort of continuous integration on my home server.